# Error when inserting strings into SQLite database from Python code

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

When I want to insert a string from `Python` code to `SQLite` database I get this error:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless
>   you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like
>   text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just
>   switch your application to Unicode strings.

This is the insert statement:

```
cur.execute("insert into links (url, title, ...) values (:url, :title, ...)", locals())
```

The string came into existence as follows:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), fromEncoding="utf-8")
html.close()
for i in soup.findAll('a'):
  url = i['href']
  title = i.renderContents()
```

Could you advise me how to insert the string into `SQLite database`?

EDIT: I found out that `url` string was OK when inserting to another table. The type of `url` string was `unicode`. The problem is when inserting `title` string. The type of `title` string is `str`.

I tried:

```
title = unicode(i.renderContents())
```

but this ends with error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
>   44: ordinal not in range(128)

thank you

Comment: use `href=True` keyword parameter; there could be `a` elements without `href` attribute. You might get `KeyError` otherwise 2. Usage of `locals()` outside debugging is frowned upon.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's good to catch `KeyError` though this wasn't the case. Why is usage of `locals()` not recommended outside debugging?

Comment: The reason I heard is that `locals()` either hides problems with the structure of your code or at best it makes the code less readable and more brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not strictly necessary for an url you could store it as Unicode.

`BeautifulSoup` works with Unicode.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""<a href="ascii">""", fromEncoding="utf-8")
>>> isinstance(soup('a', href=True)[0]['href'], unicode)
True

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""<a href="αβγ">""", fromEncoding="utf-8")
>>> soup('a', href=True)[0]['href']
u'\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3'
```

In both cases the url is `unicode`.

You could call `isinstance()` or `type()` to find out what type the url has.

---

You could specify `encoding=None` to get Unicode:

```
i.renderContents(encoding=None)
```

In general it might be helpful to use `dir(obj)`, `help(obj.method)` in a interactive Python console. See also [Printing Document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Printing%20a%20Document).

Comment: The `isinstance` and `type` helped to find out that there wasn't problem with `url` string but the problem was with `title` string. See question edit.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite only stores unicode strings.  It is most likely the URL that isn't unicode so you'll need to convert it.

You can store the URL as a blob (binary) instead but that will make life more complicated later.

Comment: You're right. My string wasn't unicode. It was `title` string, not `url` string. See question edit.